# How to change the language of dynamically data

Tags: android

I have create menu for language choose. I am gathering data by JSON so that is run-time. Now i need to change the language of contents or data so i am using this code. But it is not working.

```
     String languageToLoad  = "fa"; // your language
    Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad); 
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, 
      getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Please expert help me. is there other way for converting to language? or any library?

Comment: AFAIK..You cann't change language of data coming from webservice. For that you should have webservice which provides data in that language.

Comment: @Ketan please make sure. i think may be there other way? please check

Comment: @user1629977 You have to use a third party library that will convert runtime data to its corresponding language. https://code.google.com/p/google-translate-api-java-client/ may be helpful for you, or you can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580465/how-to-translate-one-language-to-another-using-java-programming

Answer (score 0):

```
    I think method you are using is correct. please check your language code.
    protected void language(String languageToLoad) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);   
            Locale.setDefault(locale); 
            Configuration config = new Configuration();  
            config.locale = locale;  
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,   
            getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());  
        }

   Be sure that strings file are exists in folder name appending by same language code.
```

Comment: hey, language code is correct     String languageToLoad  = "fa";

Comment: have you folder values-fa in res? if so check it out it's string file.

Comment: @BrijeshPatel He is talking about data which comes from JSON API. So how can we change language for that data ?